# Why http://localhost:8080 available while 127.0.0.1 not? (JSP on MyEclipse+Tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, localhost, myeclipse

The System's hosts file is fine, `127.0.0.1  localhost` is there...
Ping 127.0.0.1,or my IP, the result is also fine..
Myeclipse's version is 8.0 and I'm just using the Tomcat within it.
A simple JSP+Javabean web project `so` is deployed.

Now the situation is when I open MyEclipse and start the Tomcat, I can access my site throuth
`http://localhost:8080/so/index.jsp`, and it displays and runs well (this means 8080 port is all right,right?).But `http://127.0.0.1:8080/so/index.jsp` is a blank page(no source code) in K-Meleon and the page can't be found in IE.

Still when I tried to access it from another pc in LAN, 'http://myIP:8080/so/index.jsp', it worked only a little. The browser can load the homepage but without CSS, and clicking on any link or even refreshing the page leads to an error page..(While the site gose quite well on my own pc accessed throught localhost)

Is there anyone have ever met this situation?

Comment: How blank is blank page? Rightclick page -> view source. Which error exactly did IE give?

Comment: Blank means the source is nothing, and error is can't find the page..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you configured tomcat to only listen on the non-loopback interface, this is what you'd get.

See [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html) description of how this gets configured in server.xml.

Use the `netstat -a` to see what your tomcat is actually listening on.

Comment: Don't get your meaning, I didn't configure anything since it was installed with MyEclipse. So where to correct the configuration?

Comment: I am having the same issue as OP but both server.xml and netstat -an indicate that tomcat is listening on all interfaces. Any other hints ?

Comment: @kel Better to ask a new question, and be very sure that it is *precisely* the same symptoms, as this question was a curious mixture. In retrospect, I'm not sure that I understand how the answer turned out to be right.

Comment: piece of crap required only a reboot... btw I am on a hackintosh :D